# Elasticsearch BadRequest400Exception Error : main.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason"

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.4.2

I have a problem
I am using Magento 4.2.4 and Elasticsearch 6 and this message appears can anyone help me to solve it.

```
main.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [/magento2_product_2/product/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [cat]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [/magento2_product_2/product/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [cat]"},"status":400} {"exception":"[object] (Elasticsearch\\Common\\Exceptions\\BadRequest400Exception(code: 400): {\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"request [/magento2_product_2/product/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [cat]\"}],\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"request [/magento2_product_2/product/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [cat]\"},\"status\":400} at /var/www/gazazz/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:690)"} []
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether your elastic search is working properly or not or you can use these commands:

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{ "transient": { "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled": false } }'


curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```

If you are facing this issue on local then deleting all indices might solve this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply 
we testing elastic search and this the result :
https://vpc-.me-south-1.es.amazonaws.com:443
SUCCESS

Name : 9mu1E0K
Cluster name : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Elasticsearch version : 6.8.0

Comment: Seems to be that its working fine?

Comment: Unfortunately, same error message appears

Comment: [2022-11-15 08:46:25] main.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [/magento2_product_2/document/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [cat]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [/magento2_product_2/document/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [cat]"},"status":400} {"exception":"[object]

Comment: (Elasticsearch\\Common\\Exceptions\\BadRequest400Exception(code: 400): {\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"request [/magento2_product_2/document/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [cat]\"}],\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"request [/magento2_product_2/document/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [cat]\"},\"status\":400} at /var/www/gazazz/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:690)"} []

Comment: restart your elastic search and check in the env the credentials are correct

Comment: Sorry .. how i can restart your elastic search in aws

Comment: You can use this command systemctl restart elasticsearch.service

Answer (score 0):

> **Please run the below SQL:**

```
update catalog_eav_attribute cea 
join eav_attribute ea
  on ea.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id 
  and backend_type in ('text', 'varchar')
set cea.is_filterable = 0
where 
  cea.is_filterable = 1
```

> **And Run the below Commands:**

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply
After running SQL
This is the result:
Affected rows: 0 Found rows: 0 Warnings: 0 Duration for 1 query: 0.047